# Key error 'item' Spotify API - Python Flask Application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, spotify

since I'm new to APIs, I'm trying to get accustomed to using Spotify API for creating a Flask Application. I got a key error when i was trying to extract a user's recently played tracks.

```
    def get_user_last_played_tracks(self, auth_header, user_id, limit=25):
    """Get the last n tracks played by a user who logins
    :param auth_header: the authentication header
    :param user_id: the Spotify User ID when a user gets authenticated in Spotify
    :param limit: Number of tracks to get. Limit should be <= 50
    :return : List of last played n tracks from the user
    """
    last_played_api_endpoint = f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/player/recently-played?limit={limit}"
    tracks = json.loads(requests.get(last_played_api_endpoint, headers=auth_header).text)
    
    return [
        {
            'track_artist': track["track"]["artists"][0]["name"],
            'track_name': track["track"]["name"],
            'track_image': track["track"]["album"]["images"][0]["url"],
            'track_url': track["track"]["external_urls"]["spotify"],
            'track_id': track["track"]["id"]
        } for track in tracks["items"]
    ]
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Sk\anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Sk\Documents\Rhythmify\code\app.py", line 95, in select_tracks
    tracks_data = spotify_client.get_user_last_played_tracks(authorization_header, user_id, limit=25)
  File "C:\Users\Sk\Documents\Rhythmify\code\helper\spotifyclient.py", line 87, in get_user_last_played_tracks
    tracks = tracks["items"]
KeyError: 'items'
```

Comment: Try either using a debugger or print statements to see what your variables are looking like. Also please share the error message

Comment: Hi I have added the error message as well

Comment: So `tracks['items']` is not what you expected it to be (looks like tracks does not have an `items` key), so you should print out `tracks` and see what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried printing tracks I got an error:  
TypeError: string indices must be integers. Also based on Spotify API json format: "items" is the object that contains the details of the tracks, track_name, track_artist etc.

Comment: You got that error from `print(tracks)`?

Comment: Yes, its weird. I dont know.

Comment: Where did you place `print(tracks)`? Additionally, your traceback does not match the code you provided.

Comment: I placed it in the function itself which was within a class and called the function. I hope I was doing the right thing.

Comment: Also could you share `auth_header` so I can try to replicate the issue

Comment: Yes, so this is just the function. I will post the flask app function as well.